# Draw Point GeoJSON in Three.js and D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js, geojson

I want to overlay points from a GeoJSON file onto the surface of my Mars basemap using D3.js, similar to what Mike Bostock has done with a MultiLineString, as well as match the rotation angle and speed:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2b85250396c17a79155302f91ec21224

I am completely new to Three.js, but have been learning D3.js, so I am not sure how to mix the two together. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
var renderer, scene, camera;
var control;
var stats;
var cameraControl;
var radius = 15;
// Initialize the scene, camera and objects.
function init() {
  // To display anything, you need 3 things: (1) Scene, (2) Camera, (3) Renderer
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
  // Mars needs (1) geometry, (2) material, (3) mesh
  var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(15, 60, 60);
  var sphereMaterial = createMarsMaterial();
  var marsMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
  marsMesh.name = 'mars';
  scene.add(marsMesh);
  // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
  camera.position.x = 25;
  camera.position.y = 26;
  camera.position.z = 23;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
  // add controls
  cameraControl = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  // setup the control object for the control gui
  control = new function () {
    this.rotationSpeed = 0.001;
  };
  // add extras
  addControlGui(control);
  addStatsObject();
  // add the output of the renderer to the html element
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  // start animating
  render();
}
function createMarsMaterial() {
  // 4096 is the maximum width for maps  
  var marsTexture = THREE.ImageUtils;
  marsTexture.crossOrigin = "";
  
  marsTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("https://tatornator12.github.io/classes/final-project/Using_Three_-_D3/mars.jpg");
  var marsMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
  marsMaterial.map = marsTexture;
  return marsMaterial;
}
function addControlGui(controlObject) {
  var gui = new dat.GUI();
  gui.add(controlObject, 'rotationSpeed', -0.01, 0.01);
}
function addStatsObject() {
  stats = new Stats();
  stats.setMode(0);
  stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
  stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
  document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
}
function render() {
  stats.update();
  cameraControl.update();
  scene.getObjectByName('mars').rotation.y += control.rotationSpeed;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
function handleResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
window.onload = init;
window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize, false);
  
d3.json("https://tatornator12.github.io/classes/final-project/Mars_LandingSites.json", function(error, topology) {
  if (error) throw error;
  scene.add(graticule = wireframe(graticule10(), new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xaaaaaa})));
  scene.add(mesh = wireframe(topojson.mesh(topology, topology.features), new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000})));
  d3.timer(function(t) {
    graticule.rotation.x = mesh.rotation.x = Math.sin(t / 11000) * Math.PI / 3 - Math.PI / 2;
    graticule.rotation.z = mesh.rotation.z = t / 10000;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  });
});

// Converts a point [longitude, latitude] in degrees to a THREE.Vector3.
function vertex(point) {
  var lambda = point[0] * Math.PI / 180,
      phi = point[1] * Math.PI / 180,
      cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);
  return new THREE.Vector3(
    radius * cosPhi * Math.cos(lambda),
    radius * cosPhi * Math.sin(lambda),
    radius * Math.sin(phi)
  );
}

// Converts a GeoJSON MultiLineString in spherical coordinates to a THREE.LineSegments.
function wireframe(multilinestring, material) {
  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry;
  multilinestring.coordinates.forEach(function(line) {
    d3.pairs(line.map(vertex), function(a, b) {
      geometry.vertices.push(a, b);
    });
  });
  return new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
}

// See https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/issues/95
 function graticule10() {
  var epsilon = 1e-6,
      x1 = 180, x0 = -x1, y1 = 80, y0 = -y1, dx = 10, dy = 10,
      X1 = 180, X0 = -X1, Y1 = 90, Y0 = -Y1, DX = 90, DY = 360,
      x = graticuleX(y0, y1, 2.5), y = graticuleY(x0, x1, 2.5),
      X = graticuleX(Y0, Y1, 2.5), Y = graticuleY(X0, X1, 2.5);

  function graticuleX(y0, y1, dy) {
    var y = d3.range(y0, y1 - epsilon, dy).concat(y1);
    return function(x) { return y.map(function(y) { return [x, y]; }); };
  }

  function graticuleY(x0, x1, dx) {
    var x = d3.range(x0, x1 - epsilon, dx).concat(x1);
    return function(y) { return x.map(function(x) { return [x, y]; }); };
  }
 
  return {
    type: "MultiPoint",
    coordinates: d3.range(Math.ceil(X0 / DX) * DX, X1, DX).map(X)
        .concat(d3.range(Math.ceil(Y0 / DY) * DY, Y1, DY).map(Y))
        .concat(d3.range(Math.ceil(x0 / dx) * dx, x1, dx).filter(function(x) { return Math.abs(x % DX) > epsilon; }).map(x))
        .concat(d3.range(Math.ceil(y0 / dy) * dy, y1 + epsilon, dy).filter(function(y) { return Math.abs(y % DY) > epsilon; }).map(y))
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to go fullscreen */
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tatornator12.github.io/classes/final-project/Using_Three_-_D3/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://tatornator12.github.io/classes/final-project/Using_Three_-_D3/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://tatornator12.github.io/classes/final-project/Using_Three_-_D3/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tatornator12.github.io/classes/final-project/Using_Three_-_D3/stats.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i would like to know this aswell...